# Unable to lunch android project on emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Right now i am trying to display some text on the screen,but my project is not getting launch and i could not find the accurate reason.Has any one met this situation?

***Here i have given you every thing in detail for your reference.please find below***

**LOGCAT**

```
08-13 16:02:58.823: D/AndroidRuntime(336): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
08-13 16:02:58.823: D/AndroidRuntime(336): CheckJNI is ON
08-13 16:02:58.953: D/AndroidRuntime(336): --- registering native functions ---
08-13 16:02:59.483: D/AndroidRuntime(336): Shutting down VM
08-13 16:02:59.483: D/dalvikvm(336): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-13 16:02:59.522: I/AndroidRuntime(336): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
```

**Console**

```
[2012-08-13 15:50:55 - print_testing] ------------------------------
[2012-08-13 15:50:55 - print_testing] Android Launch!
[2012-08-13 15:50:55 - print_testing] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-13 15:50:55 - print_testing] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-08-13 15:50:55 - print_testing] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2012-08-13 15:50:55 - print_testing] Performing sync
[2012-08-13 15:50:55 - print_testing] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Android22-API-8'
[2012-08-13 15:50:56 - print_testing] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2012-08-13 15:50:56 - print_testing] \print_testing\bin\print_testing.apk installed on device
[2012-08-13 15:50:56 - print_testing] Done!
```

**DisplayActivity.java**

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity
{   
EditText edt1,edt2;
Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main1);


edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 

{

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{

if(edt1.getText().toString().equals("4545"))
{

String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
System.out.println("Student name : Karan" + newLine + "Total no of Working days : 25" 
+ newLine +"Total no of present days : 23 " + newLine + "Total no of Absent days : 2");
        }
    }
});
 }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.print.testing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN1" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Look at your manifest file you had used `android.intent.action.MAIN1` why is it so? It should be `android.intent.action.MAIN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml . Its not

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN1" />
```

it should be

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your AndroidManifest.xml file should contain this instead of "MAIN1" main is action not a xml